# Invoking psftp using powershell

Tags: powershell

My powershell code does not work when invoking PSFTP commands:

current code:

```
    invoke-expression "psftp.exe -i key.ppk ubuntu@remoteserver -be b sftpcommands.txt > logs.log"
```

I have tried the following:

```
    invoke-command "psftp.exe -i key.ppk ubuntu@remoteserver -be b sftpcommands.txt > logs.log"
```

and this

```
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "psftp.exe -i key.ppk ubuntu@remoteserver -be b sftpcommands.txt > logs.log"
```

Running this in cmd prompt without the use of powershell works fine

```
    psftp.exe -i key.ppk ubuntu@remoteserver -be b sftpcommands.txt > logs.log
```

Comment: Are you just trying to start psftp locally? You don't need `invoke-command` for that.

Comment: No, I have a remote server. I just replaced my actual remote server IP with 192.168.1.1 for this post. Updated the contents so as not to confuse

Comment: Perhaps try `invoke-expression  '& psftp.exe -i key.ppk ubuntu@remoteserver -be b sftpcommands.txt > logs.log'`

Comment: Im sorry but does not work still

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is is complaining about psftp.exe not being recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, etc.? If so, you have to do `.\psftp.exe`.

Comment: I tried .\psftp.exe and here are the results:

   PuTTY Secure File Transfer (SFTP) client
   Release 0.62
   Usage: psftp [options] [user@]host
   Options:
     -V        print version information and exit
     -pgpfp    print PGP key fingerprints and exit
     
     etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up restructuring my code to:

```
invoke-expression (.\psftp.exe 'remoteserver' -l 'ubuntu' -i key.ppk -v -b 'sftpcommands.txt' > 'logs.log') 2> $null
```